# Limit size of entered data in tinyMCE 5

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I use tinyMCE 5 in my web site to enter data stored in a database. Therefore I need to limit the entered size, including format information, to the size of the data field. How can I prohibit the user to enter more then the allowed number of bytes, say 2000?

Best of all if I could add some information like "**42/2000**" on the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement in our project (difference: the output should be <entered_chars>/<chars_left> instead of <entered_chars>/<max_chars>), and it ended up being a custom plugin, based on the wordcount plugin. There is some hacks in there, which could make it fail whenever tinyMCE changes, since there is no API for the statusbar in version 5 at this point of time.
But maybe you will still find it useful:

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var global = tinymce.util.Tools.resolve('tinymce.PluginManager');

  var maxChars = function (editor) {
    return editor.getParam('number_max_chars', 3600);
  };
  var applyMaxChars = function (editor) {
    return editor.getParam('restrict_to_max_chars', true);
  };
  var Settings = {
    maxChars: maxChars,
    applyMaxChars: applyMaxChars
  };

  var global$1 = tinymce.util.Tools.resolve('tinymce.dom.TreeWalker');

  var getText = function (node, schema) {
    var blockElements = schema.getBlockElements();
    var shortEndedElements = schema.getShortEndedElements();
    var isNewline = function (node) {
      return blockElements[node.nodeName] || shortEndedElements[node.nodeName];
    };
    var textBlocks = [];
    var txt = '';
    var treeWalker = new global$1(node, node);
    while (node = treeWalker.next()) {
      if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        txt += node.data;
      } else if (isNewline(node) && txt.length) {
        textBlocks.push(txt);
        txt = '';
      }
    }
    if (txt.length) {
      textBlocks.push(txt);
    }
    return textBlocks;
  };

  var strLen = function (str) {
    return str.replace(/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g, '_').length;
  };
  var countCharacters = function (node, schema) {
    var text = getText(node, schema).join('');
    return strLen(text);
  };
  var createBodyCounter = function (editor, count) {
    return function () {
      return count(editor.getBody(), editor.schema);
    };
  };
  var createMaxCount = function (editor) {
    return function () {
      return Settings.maxChars(editor);
    }
  }
  var createRestrictToMaxCount = function (editor) {
    return function () {
      return Settings.applyMaxChars(editor);
    }
  }
  var get = function (editor) {
    return {
      getCount: createBodyCounter(editor, countCharacters),
      getMaxCount: createMaxCount(editor),
      getRestrictToMaxCount: createRestrictToMaxCount(editor)
    };
  };
  var global$2 = tinymce.util.Tools.resolve('tinymce.util.Delay');

  function isAllowedKeycode(event) {
    // allow arrow keys, backspace and delete
    const key = event.keyCode;
    return key === 37 || key === 38 || key === 39 || key === 40 || key === 8
        || key === 46;
  }

  var updateCount = function (editor, api) {
    editor.getContainer().getElementsByClassName(
        'tox-statusbar__text-container')[0].textContent = String(
        api.getCount()) + " / " + String(
        Settings.maxChars(editor) - api.getCount());
  };
  var setup = function (editor, api, delay) {
    var debouncedUpdate = global$2.debounce(function () {
      return updateCount(editor, api);
    }, delay);
    editor.on('init', function () {
      updateCount(editor, api);
      global$2.setEditorTimeout(editor, function () {
        editor.on('SetContent BeforeAddUndo Undo Redo keyup', debouncedUpdate);
        editor.on('SetContent BeforeAddUndo Undo Redo keydown', function (e) {
          if (!isAllowedKeycode(e) && Settings.applyMaxChars(editor) &&
              api.getCount() >= Settings.maxChars(editor)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
          }
        });
      }, 0);
    });
  };

  function Plugin(delay) {
    if (delay === void 0) {
      delay = 300;
    }
    global.add('charactercount', function (editor) {
      var api = get(editor);
      setup(editor, api, delay);
      return api;
    });
  }

  Plugin();

}());
```

Currently I'm working on a preprocessor for the paste plugin, so that the max_length effects also pasted text. That's why you see the charactercount API in the code.